# Python Django : adding constrained field value into CBV view without all fields displayes

Tags: python, django

I am using a ClassBasedView, and asking Django to remove some fields in the auto-generated form (letting out :  owner / owner_card_nb ) :

```
class BristolCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model       = Bristol
    fields      = [ "catalogue"            ,
                    "recommanded_age"       ,
                    "title"                 ,
                    "url"                   ,
                    "path_illustration"     ,
                    "description"           ] #letting out :  owner / owner_card_nb
```

I have to calculate the field owner_car_nb  when the form is sent to the server.

```
owner_card_nb= Bristol.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

How can I push this data into the form which has been displayed in the html without the owner, neither the owner_car_nb value ?

I tried several methods :

1. Adding get_initial to the CBV :

   ```
    class BristolCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
        def get_initial(self):
            return {'owner': self.request.user.id,
                'owner_card_nb': 1}
   ```

But the webpage still fails :

```
IntegrityError at /bristol/create
NOT NULL constraint failed: bristol_bristol.owner_id
```

2. using form_valid :

   ```
   def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
    form.instance.owner_card_nb= Bristol.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
    return super(BristolCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
   ```

But the webpage still fails :

```
IntegrityError at /bristol/create
NOT NULL constraint failed: bristol_bristol.owner_id
```

What do I do wrong ?
How can we set up values in a CBV form for non-displayed fields ?

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the `form_valid` : I put `created_by` instead of `owner`...